# htaccess filtering settings

Tags: apache, .htaccess, filtering, flags

I have this site like a search engine When i type a search the url looks like `mysite.com/search/free/**video/keyword**.html` instead of `mysite.com/?search=**keyword**&type=**video**` and i have small issue with this. For example if a search tag contain spaces, + or -, my url is not getting rewrited. I get query strings url like ?search=**key+word**&type=**video**  and i don't know how to get rid of this. 
This is my htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=(\w+)&type=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com\/search\/free\/%2\/%1.html? [R,L,B]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html?$ index.php?search=$1&page=$2&type=$3 [L]
```

I tryed adding changing $1 with ${escape:$1} and added RewriteMap escape int:escape in my httpd.conf file but still no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your first rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^search=([^&]+)&type=([^&]+)$
RewriteRule ^ http://mysite.com\/search\/free\/%2\/%1.html? [R,L,NE]
```